Do either Biden or Harris currently support a public option for Obamacare?
In the 2020 Democratic Primaries, President Biden supported adding a public health insurance option to Obamacare, and Vice President Harris supported replacing Obamacare with Medicare for All.  But now Harris has shifted her position from Medicare for All to preserving and strengthening Obamacare.  My question is, what are Biden and Harris’ current position on a public option?
Did Biden weigh in on the public option during his 2024 Presidential campaign?  Has Harris weighed in on the issue since taking over for Biden?
EDIT: To clarify, a public option would be a government-run health insurance plan that would compete with the private health insurance plans offered in the Obamacare exchanges.

Can you clarify what you mean by "public health insurance option"?  Given that Obamacare as a whole would seem to qualify for that definition?  What kind of adjustment would that consist of?  May be obvious to some, but at guess only people who follow this subject very, very, closely.

@ItalianPhilosophers4Monica Obamacare provides a marketplace for private insurance companies, and offers subsidies to low-income people, but doesn't have an insurance option provided by the government itself.

@Barmar So, what that means is Obamacare becoming a possible provider itself, either directly or via some entity acting on its behalf?  Stating that would be a lot clearer in this Q.

@ItalianPhilosophers4Monica https://www.healthinsurance.org/glossary/public-option/ It was a well-understood concept during the debate over the ACA.

@ItalianPhilosophers4Monica I added a clarification.

Thanks.  Obviously people who don't know the term might not be the most qualified to answer, but it's good of you to clarify what you are asking about for the rest of us.



Question:
Do either Biden or Harris currently supports a public option for Obamacare?


Short answer,
no.  The affordable care act as passed was modest reform.   Even this however consumed 5-6 years of President Obamas administration.  Nobody but perhaps Bernie wants to revisit or get more ambitious on healthcare until once again it can’t be avoided do to economic liabilities of the status quo.
Currently reformers in healthcare are focusing on smaller bites like pharma drug price gouging rather than reforming the entire Gordian knot.
Introducing a public option would impose real competition on a private healthcare system long devoid of such market pressures.  It would cost the private industries trillions and likely replace the decades old private healthcare segment with public healthcare system.
Longer Answer
Three thoughts.

About a third of the U.S healthcare system prior to the Affordable Care Act was public / run by the federal government.  Medicare and Medicaid, consisting of poor folks or older folks who generally can't afford private care.   Another Third of the American population went without healthcare coverage unable to afford private health insurance and not being eligible for Medicare or Medicaid. Finally, only about a third of the population was enrolled in the private care system.

US private insurance companies do not compete, they collude.  By design they operate outside the free market like a cartel or a monopoly.  They are legally excluded from federal antitrust laws since 1948 by the McCarran Ferguson Act.  So trying to introduce competition between a public option private option designed to work absent competition, consumer choice and the free market is a formula for cataclysmic instability and sudden dramatic change.  The affordable care act as crafted was always modest reform not wholesale replacement.  It was designed to save the American consumer / government modestly while expanding the customer base of the private insurance companies by millions.

The affordable care act limits overhead for insurance companies to around 20% which was seen as significant even draconian at the time given many Insurance companies regularly operated at much higher overhead costs.  Medicare and Medicaid each operate at under 5% overhead.  Thus, if there was a competition it would be one sided.  A fact not lost on the insurance companies who negotiated and approved the affordable care act with the Obama administration prior to funding its critics and committing its resources to block its ratification.


